# Every element in a ring different from 0 is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

True or false.All number  r in a ring R,  different from 0 is same.

It seems like it is true but how to go about proof if we consider Matrix then it is invertible if determinant is not 0 .

Answer (score 6):

This is not true, as then it would imply that every ring in which $0\neq 1$ is a field.

Simple examples include $\mathbb{Z}$, but we can go further to show just how badly the conjecture can fail by showing that there are rings containing zero divisors (i.e. elements $a\neq 0$ such that there exists $b\neq 0$ where $ab=0$):

As an example, consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ equipped with addition modulo $n$ and multiplication modulo $n$, where $n$ is composite.

As another simple example, take the ring of all $n\times n$ matrices over any field, and consider the matrix where the top left corner is $1$ and the rest of the entries are $0$ (e.g. for $n=2$ this would be $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$).  This has determinant zero and thus is not invertible, but is non-zero.

Comment: Isn't just ${\bf Z}$ a simpler example?

Comment: @tomasz Very true!  These examples have the added benefit of having zero divisors, though, showing just how badly the conjecture can fail.  I'll add your simpler example though.

Answer (score 2):

As an another good example in addition to Hayden's response, one could just consider the ring of integers: $R=\mathbb{Z}$. The only invertible elements in this ring are $1$ and $-1$.  To make this clear, suppose $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ is invertible. then there is some $a^{-1}\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1$. But $aa^{-1}=1$ implies that $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}\in \mathbb{Q}$, clearly $a^{-1}$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a=1$ or $-1$.